# Include a vars.yml file inside group_vars/all.yml

Tags: ansible

I want to include variables from a file (say `vars.yml`) and use it inside `group_vars/all.yml`.

How this can be achieved?
tried (in `all.yml`):

```
include_vars: 
  file: ../inventories/dev/cluster-0/group_vars/vars.yml
  name: x
ansible_user: "{{ x.username }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`include_vars` is an ansible *task*, and can only appear in a playbook or task list. A variable file can only contain variables; there's no "include"-style mechanism.

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you can turn `all.yml` into a directory (`group_vars/all/`) and then place multiple files in that directory:

```
group_vars/all/file1.yaml
group_vars/all/file2.yaml
```